# WebRTC how to get user private IP without disable browser flag

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I need get user ip. But my services place behind corp proxy. So I can't use https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace API and other services.

I use WebRTC but, i get ip in uid. How to decrypt uid to get user IP?

Code to get user IP

```
window.RTCPeerConnection =
    window.RTCPeerConnection ||
    window.mozRTCPeerConnection ||
    window.webkitRTCPeerConnection; //compatibility for Firefox and chrome

var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [] }),
    noop = function() {};

pc.createDataChannel(""); //create a bogus data channel

// create offer and set local description
  pc.createOffer(pc.setLocalDescription.bind(pc), noop);     
  pc.onicecandidate = function(ice) {
    if (ice && ice.candidate && ice.candidate.candidate) {

let myIp = ice.candidate.address;
      alert(myIp);
      pc.onicecandidate = noop;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The uuid you getting is mDNS of your machine in a local network. It was introduced to prevent webrtc from leaking local ip addresses. For a detailed explanation see [this article](https://bloggeek.me/psa-mdns-and-local-ice-candidates-are-coming/).

From terminal, mDNS can be resolved into an ip address with ping:

```
$ ping <uuid>.local
PING <uuid>.local (<ip_address>): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from <ip_address>: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.559 ms
```

But I don't think there's a good way to get ip from mDNS with javascript – it's exactly the point why it was introduced.

There might be some cheeky ways of resolving it with java applets or flash. But if one uses techs like this, you probably don't need webrtc to find his local address.

Comment: i get error: 
Ping failed to find node <uid>.local